# Does this count as recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm learning about recursions and I have to later apply it a project. My project is going to include a deck of cards and I'm just curious if this counts as recursion? To me it seems like it since it calls itself. However since i'm still learning I want to make sure i'm understanding the concept and i'm not wrong. Please let me know.

```
string Card::suitName(Suit S) {
    string suits;

    switch (S) {
        case clubs:
            suits = "Clubs";
            break;
        case diamonds:
            suits = "Diamonds";
            break;
        case hearts:
            suits = "Hearts";
            break;
        case spades:
            suits = "Spades";
            break;
    }
    return (suits);
}

// declare the value of the cards
string Card::cardValue(Value Card) {
    string card;

    switch (Card) {
        case two:
            card = "Two";
            break;
        case three:
            card = "Three";
            break;
        case four:
            card = "Four";
            break;
        case five:
            card = "Five";
            break;
        case six:
            card = "Six";
            break;
        case seven:
            card = "Seven";
            break;
        case eight:
            card = "Eight";
            break;
        case nine:
            card = "Nine";
            break;
        case ten:
            card = "Ten";
            break;
        case jack:
            card = "Jack";
            break;
        case queen:
            card = "Queen";
            break;
        case king:
            card = "King";
            break;
        case ace:
            card = "Ace";
            break;
    }
    return (card);
}
```

Comment: No. The method `suitName` does not call `suitName`, and the method `cardValue` does not call `cardValue`.

Comment: @Naetmul if `suitName` calls `cardValue` and `cardValue` calls `suitName` then it's also a recursion. But it's not like that in this case

Answer (score 1):

You've defined two functions `Card::suitName()` and `Card::cardValue()`. Neither function calls itself or any other user-defined function (excluding any `std::string` functions). There's no recursion anywhere in your code.

Comment: Oh I see I jumped ahead of myself and was thinking return(suits); was return(suitName); Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is defined as a function calling itself within itself. So `suitName` would need to have a call to `suitName` or `cardValue` to `cardValue.` Neither make such a call, so

**There is no recursion in your code**

Comment: Oh I see I jumped ahead of myself and was thinking return(suits); was return(suitName);  Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

Recursion requires a function to call itself (most commonly directly but it can be via another function).

Example:

```
bool doesHandContainAceRecursion(std::vector<Card> const& playersCards, int pos) {
    // If we have tried all the cards and gone past the end
    // Then return false.
    //
    // This is a classic part of recursion, checking if you have reached the end.
    if (pos >= playersCards.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Otherwise do the work you want to do.
    if (playersCards[pos].value == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    // This is the recursive call.
    // It calls itself. This is a classic example of tail recursion.
    return doesHandContainAceRecursion(playersCards, pos + 1);
}

// This is the function you call and it sets up a call to the
// recursive function above.
bool doesHandContainAce(std::vector<Card> const& playersCards) {
    return doesHandContainAceRecursion(playersCards, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not recursions. Recursions is when method is calling itself

Example:

```
string Card::suitName(Suit S) {
    string suits;

    switch (S) {
        case clubs:
            suitName(diamonds); // Recursions
            break;
        case diamonds:
            suits = "Diamonds";
            break;
    }
    return (suits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the code you provided does not involve recursion. Recursion is a programming technique where a function calls itself, either directly or indirectly, to solve a problem. In the code you provided, there are no function calls that reference the function itself.

The functions suitName and cardValue are simply taking in an input and returning a corresponding output based on a switch statement. They do not involve any kind of iterative or recursive process to arrive at the output.

In the context of a deck of cards, you might consider using recursion for a function that shuffles the cards, as shuffling involves repeatedly swapping pairs of cards until the deck is randomized. However, the code you provided does not involve recursion.